# How to serve a frontend that gets data from a rails API server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, backbone.js, client-side

We have decided to go with a rails JSON only API server for our new project since different clients need to access it.

I'm thinking about how the frontend could be served to the browser. As I see it I could

> **EITHER**
>
> have a javascript heavy client built on top of a client side MVC like
>   Backbone that accesses the API server directly
>
> **OR**
>
> have the frontend server make some of the API calls and render the html to the client. Some APIs would still be accessed from client JS. A lot of the processing and routing logic would reside in the server.

I'm hesitant to go with the first option due to it being more heavy on the client and less SEO friendly. Also making the client an SPA is not a priority.

I'm looking for advice and comments on the second option. Is this approach recommended ? What would be a good choice for the FE server in that case ? I'm thinking of having a separate rails FE server that talks to the rails API server.